# Una lista de un arreglo de estructuras c#

Tags: c#, array, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Hola soy aun novato aprendiendo c# y me encontre con este ejercicio /*Amplia el programa del ejercicio 4.3.1.1, para que almacene datos de hasta 100 canciones. 
Deberá tener un menú que permita las opciones: añadir una nueva canción, mostrar el título
de todas las canciones, buscar la canción que contenga un cierto texto (en el artista o en el título).
*/ donde al principio solo era crear la estructura con los datos, pero al momento de crear el menu para que pueda introducir una cancion a esta lista con canciones.add() no me lo permite porque segun esta sobrecargada, si me pudieran ayudar lo agradeceria, es para mi practica personal ya que estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta. y si estoy usando el using System.Collection.Generic

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace practica4
{
    struct cancion
    {
        public string formatoCancion;
        public string artista;
        public string titulo;
        public int duracion;
        public int tamañoFichero;


}

class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {


        cancion[] Arreglocancion = new cancion[100];
        List <cancion> canciones = new List <cancion> (Arreglocancion);

        Console.WriteLine ("seleccione una accion a realizar");

        Console.WriteLine ("1) Añadir una nueva cancion "); 

        Console.WriteLine ("2) Mostrar el titulo de todas las canciones ");

        Console.WriteLine ("3) Buscar las canciones que contengan un cierto texto (en el artista o titulo) ");

        int seleccion = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());

        switch (seleccion) {

        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine ("Inserte el nombre de la cancion que quiera añadir: ");
            string nuevaCancion = Console.ReadLine ();
            canciones.Add (nuevaCancion);
            break;

        default: Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una opcion validad del menu ");break;



        }


        }

    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es necesario pasarle un array de canciones con el tamaño 100 al `List<T>`, este es dinamico y mientras agregues canciones seguira creciendo. Y controlas cuantos items quieres agregar.

```
 List <cancion> canciones = new List <cancion> ();


  case 1:
        Console.WriteLine ("Inserte el nombre de la cancion que quiera añadir: ");
        string nuevaCancion = Console.ReadLine ();

        if(canciones.Count <= 100)
           canciones.Add(new cancion(nuevaCancion));

        break;
```

Si tu Clase Canción solo tiene un string como propiedad podrías simplificar tu programa haciendo un `List<string>` y no una clase por una sola propiedad. Pero debes evaluar primero.

```
 List <string> canciones = new List <string> ();

 case 1:
        Console.WriteLine ("Inserte el nombre de la cancion que quiera añadir: ");
        string nuevaCancion = Console.ReadLine ();

        if(canciones.Count <= 100)
           canciones.Add(nuevaCancion);

        break;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me estaba complicando mas de lo necesario

Answer (score 0):

//aqui mi ejemplo de solucion

```
switch (seleccion) {

    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine ("Inserte el nombre de la cancion que quiera añadir: ");
        string formato = Console.ReadLine ();
       // aqui debes llenar con lo leido en consola. para el ejemplo solo lei el formato, lo demas lo puse directo 
               canciones.Add(new cancion { formatoCancion = formato, artista = "Juan", titulo = "amor", duracion = 20, tamañoFichero=300 });

            //para demostrar que funciona mira que el formato de la cancion fue leida desde el teclado.
            foreach (cancion p in canciones)
             {
                      Console.WriteLine(p.titulo+"  "+ p.artista +" "+p.formatoCancion+"\n");
                 }
            Console.ReadKey();
        break;

    default: Console.WriteLine("Ingrese una opcion validad del menu ");break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido [es.so]. Si bien tú respuesta puede que solucione la pregunta, es recomendable indicar el porque es válida, para que quien la pueda leer, aprenda de ella, y pueda servir a otros usuarios. Adicionalmente puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].